# How can a cloth simulated sail be prevented from flying away?

Tags: cloth-simulation, force-fields

I added a cloth simulation to a canvas and want it to be moved by a wind force. The sail is blown away. How can this be prevented?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few vertices should be added to a vertex group:

[image]

this vertex group is assigned in the cloth settings with ticked *Pin* option.

[image]

Besides that I found that a vortex works better than plain wind force.

[image]