# Difference between the vortex and the wind force

Tags: cloth-simulation, force-fields

In a recent [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/12173/2217), stacker stated that the vortex is better then the wind force for cloth simulations.
What is the difference between the vortex and the wind? How does each relate to cloth simulations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was for the use case when the cloth is pinned. Animating a flag (with a loose end) a wind force works well.

By using a wind force the sail in the scene stopped fluttering after a few frames like blown up. Which is probably more realistic if you have steady wind from one direction.

Since I wanted it wobble I tested a vortex which  behaves more dynamically, more like a fan where the airflow changes it's strength and also allows the canvas to retract.

[image]

Comment: So the vortex adds noise to the wind. Is that a correct summary?

Comment: @David Noise is random, a vortex is rather a rotating force. You can see this clearliy when you emit particles and let them move by a vortex. See the difference yourself, I've uploaded the test file here: http://pasteall.org/blend/29765

Comment: @David The [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Force_Fields) has an explaination of all the force fields. Just scroll down to wind and vortex. In short: wind is a constant force in a given direction, while vortex (as stacker said) is a rotating force, that can also suck affected objects toward its center (or push them outwards). Just like a maelstrom.

Comment: @maddin45 I have read the wiki on force fields, and that is why I was surprised by stacker's use like a wind force. To quote the wiki "spiraling force that twists the direction of points around the force object’s local Z axis." I did not think that it would  have a constant wind type of force as well.

Comment: @David There is an option to add noise to a wind force, here's a [screenshot](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/72580).